# Combine a dataframe and a list of dataframes into a one-dimensional list of dataframes, R

Tags: r, dataframe

This should be pretty easy, but I dont know how. I have a single dataframe and a list with two dataframes. Now I want to combine them together, so that I have a single list with three dataframes. And I do not want to do in "manually".

```
a = data.frame(xa = 1:10,
               ya = 11:20)
b = list(c = data.frame(x = 1:10),
         d = data.frame(x = 1:20,
                        y = 11:30))
```

Now I though about something like this:

```
res = c(a, b)
```

But this results in this:

```
> sapply(res, class)
          xa           ya            c            d 
   "integer"    "integer" "data.frame" "data.frame"
```

So it turns the two columns of the single dataframe into a vector.
How could I maintain the dataframe structure for the "single" dataframe and extract the dataframes from the list of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `c` but you have to cover your `data.frame` a into a list.

```
res <- c(b, list(a=a))

str(res)
#List of 3
# $ c:'data.frame':      10 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ x: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ d:'data.frame':      20 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ x: int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  ..$ y: int [1:20] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
# $ a:'data.frame':      10 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ xa: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  ..$ ya: int [1:10] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always add it as a new element

```
b[["a"]]=a
```

The "a" can be used in a loop or something similar.